# Use npm module for front end dependencies failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

I thought I can do npm instead of bower, what I did is do `npm install angular --save`, then include it like this

`<script src="../node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>`

but it seems the path is incorrect. I create a temp repo to showcase my folder structure.

https://github.com/eldyvoon/temp/

Comment: I didn't see `node_modules` folder in your repo. Please ensure you've successfully set up `NPM`.

Comment: @Vineet try to clone and run `npm install`. usually people put node_modules folder in .gitignore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in order to use node_modules you have to expose the direcotry with browsersync.

try this, change like this the browser-sync gulp task in gulfile.js:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init(null, {
        server: {
            baseDir: 'app',
            routes: {
                '/node_modules': './node_modules'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

In your index.html your jquery  import is wrong, use this:

```
<script src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps, let me know if you need more infos

Comment: are you sure this is the problem? even i refresh it manually I still got the error angularjs file is not loaded

Comment: I've tryed on your project. Have you restart browsersync? If you wan I can create a pull request on jour github project

Comment: I created a pull request on your project

Comment: thanks! but angularjs is still not working, I'd pushed my code @rick

Comment: the problem with dependencies is solved? If so create another question so we can look at it. and maybe give me the answere :)

Comment: btw I'm looking at you'r problem, expect another pull request soon ;)

Comment: pull this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37789448/gulp-isnt-building-my-js-file-on-dist